# View all workspaces/projects in Adobe Analytics (Site Catalyst

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

We are in the process of documenting our Analytics implementation and, after speaking with the business users, have learned that instead of scheduled reports they are using Workspaces to glean information.

I've looked all over the site, consulted the Help section, and googled... but I can't figure out if there is anyway for me (as an admin) to see and manage all workspaces/projects.

Is this doable?

Comment: This is not a question about coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

Workspace > Manage Projects > Other Filters > Show All

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to follow that process (Workspace > Manage Projects > Other Filters > Show All). You will see all the projects and from there you can manage all of them.

[image]